# Cordova's splash screen doesn't show

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, splash-screen

I am building a small mobile app using Cordova + AngularJS, so far so good. But I spent the whole day trying to get the splash screen to show, and failed.

Here is my global config.xml

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="WebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverScroll" value="false"/>
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
<preference name="Detect-data-types" value="true"/>
<preference name="Stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
<preference name="Android-targetSdkVersion" value="22"/>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<preference name="LoadingDialog" value="Loading, Please wait!"/>
<platform name="android">
    <splash src="www/res/screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen.png" density="xhdpi"/>
</platform>
```

I have installed Cordova's splash screen plugin successfully, and the path `www/res/screen.png` is correct and the screen.png gets moved to the `/platforms/android/res/drawable-**` folders successfully. I also tried using `navigator.splashscreen.show`, But still, the screen doesn't show up!

I tried every solution ever posted regarding this problem and it just wont work. The only way I could get the splash screen to show was by using Intel XDK build/icons & splash screen options, but the build process happens at the XDK servers and I wanna be able to just hit `cordova run/emulate/build android` and see the results with out XDK middling.

I am loosing my mind here, any help would be appreciated.
I am using Corodva 5.0.0, Angular 1.4.4, on an emulator (Intel atom 64), debugging via Chrome device inspection tools.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here. Did you find any solutions?

Comment: NO, sadly. Had to ship the app without it !